# I use a special package for ZKTeco in Laravel, which is a attendance It works on localhost but not on hosting

Tags: package, laravel-9, zkteco

The problem is that the code works on localhost and does not work on hosting, and the following message appears
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9FAi.png)

I suspect the problem is that I am using shared hosting
But I want a solution to the problem if it is through shared hosting